# uri too long returning from ajax post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

When I call this JS:

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/renderscooter',
        data: { img: imgSrc, deimg: imgDe, newimg: img}
    })
    .done(function( html ) {
        jQuery('#content_illu').css('background-image', 'data:image/png;base64,'+html);
        jQuery('#content_illu').css('background-size','auto 737px');
    });
```

I expect the new image created dinamically is displayed on the browser, but I get:

```
414 Request-URI Too Large
```

I see the image comes with the URL:

```
 http://pg251.inetpsa.com/configure/iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAB4AAAAQ4C....
```

and this is strange to me.

How could avoid this problem?

The image is sent back to the ajax call from a zf2 php controller method like:

```
... creation of the image ...
ob_start();
//ImagePng($imgPng, $dstImagePathName);
ImagePng($imgPng);
ImageDestroy($imgPng);
$imageData = ob_get_clean();

$response = $this->getResponse();
$response
->getHeaders()
->addHeaderLine('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary')
->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'image/png')
->addHeaderLine('Content-Length', mb_strlen($imageData));
//$response->setContent('url("'.$dstImageName.'")');
$response->setContent(base64_encode($imageData));
return $response;
```

Thanks for your time.

**EDIT**

Finally I avoided the ajax method, and use this approach:
[change background-image to other one created dynamically by ajax call script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055685/change-background-image-to-other-one-created-dinamically-by-ajax-call-script)

Comment: why `content-type image/png`? You are sending back text

Comment: you are right, i don't need to set thats ... anyway the problem is not solved. I also removed base64 encoding. I don't get the long uri now, but instead the image is displayed I see a chunk of bytes as response with firebug. I tried different ways but at least I store the image to disk and return que url(path) as response to the Ajax call I can't get the image change (displayed). I am trying to avoid writting the image to disk becasue requirements.

Comment: does it work in a php page on server, no ajax, just output an image tag with data in it?

Comment: also you need `url` part of background image  http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming You're using Apache Web Server. Under Apache, there is a configurable value, **[`LimitRequestLine`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestline)**. If you want to support a longer request URI, Change that value to something larger than the default.

From http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestline :

> "This directive sets the number of bytes that will be allowed on the HTTP request-line. The LimitRequestLine directive allows the server administrator to set the limit on the allowed size of a client's HTTP request-line. Since the request-line consists of the HTTP method, URI, and protocol version, the LimitRequestLine directive places a restriction on the length of a request-URI allowed for a request on the server. A server needs this value to be large enough to hold any of its resource names, including any information that might be passed in the query part of a GET request."

Comment: Even if: Under normal conditions, the value should not be changed from the default. Also, you can't set this higher than 8190 without modifying the source and rebuilding. I can change the Limit, but now I get Forbidden. Strange since it is a binary chunk of bytes to display, nothing related with permission ...

Comment: mm..Just try with $.ajax instead of jquery.ajax

Comment: Since I know jQuery is more exact than $ since $ is an abbreviation. Btw I've changed and still forbidden.. Anyway when I don't have this long query through other tries the image is not displayed anyway ... and I can only see a chunk of bytes with firebug.