# change background-image to other one created dynamically by ajax call script

Tags: javascript, php

I am looking for the way to avoid image storage when use the GD function ImagePng, but use image created to change a background-image property on an element.

I've written an ajax call to the php script that creates the image, and when done I want to use the response as the image to set as background for the element.

My problem is the new created image is not displayed but with firebug I can see the response as a chunk of bytes.

Is possible what am I trying to achieve? or 
I must store the image and use its reference, mandatory?

Here is the main part of the code:

Ajax call:

```
    jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/renderscooter',
            proccessData: false,
            data: { img: imgSrc, deimg: imgDe, newimg: img}
        })
        .done(function( html ) {
//            jQuery('#content_illu').css('background-image', html);
//            jQuery('#content_illu').css('background-image', 'url('+html+')');
//            jQuery('#content_illu').css('background-image', 'data:image/png;basa64,'+html);
            jQuery('#content_illu').css('background-image', 'data:image/png;'+html);
            jQuery('#content_illu').css('background-size','auto 737px');
        });
```

PHP Controller:

```
...
... creation image process 
...
    ob_start();
    //ImagePng($imgPng, $dstImagePathName);
    ImagePng($imgPng);
    ImageDestroy($imgPng);
    $imageData = ob_get_clean();

    $response = $this->getResponse();
    $response
    ->getHeaders()
    ->addHeaderLine('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary')
    //->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'image/png')
    ->addHeaderLine('Content-Length', mb_strlen($imageData));
    //$response->setContent('url("'.$dstImageName.'")');
    //$response->setContent(base64_encode($imageData));
    $response->setContent($imageData);
    return $response;
```

NOTE:
If I store the image and return the string: `$response->setContent('url("'.$dstImageName.'")');`

it works setting after done at the ajax call:

```
jQuery('#content_illu').css('background-image', html);
```

but due to requirements the image might not be written on disk.

Comment: I don't think passing binary data to the elements style tag will work ?

Comment: And if you uncomment the base64 function and pass base64, make sure you add the `image/png` stuff at the beginning of the string etc.

Comment: and why it works for <img src="script.php" ... > ?¿

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple solutions.

- Return base64 encoded image as a string (make sure to also use the proper content length
- Use a GET request instead of a POST request, and just set the background-image css attribute to the GET request url rather than using AJAX at all.

Comment: first thing, I tried ... or am i doing something wrong?, you can see at the code the commented line, in that case I use data:image/png;basa64,'+html to set the background-image. Also I was having uri too long problems (solved changing apache directive) and the result was the same. No image displayed and with firebug see the chunk of code

Comment: second solution i will try, but i guess i will fall into uri too long  too

Comment: sorry, with the first solution once I solve theuri too long think, I get forbidden

Comment: @manou - the Second solution will not cause a URI too long problem because the css will be like *** background-image: url('/getimage?a=1&b=2&c=3'); ***. As for the first solution, browsers tend to have a limit on the size of DATA URIs so if your generate background image is too larger (< ~32K) it probably won't work as a DATA URI. For small simple images where the background is tiled it would work fine. You can test this by copy and pasting the DATA URI into your browser's URL bar.